# Implementing a CoverFlow View

Tags: ios, xcode, coverflow

I have to create a view where I have to put in a CoverFlow of Images.
How can I crete it?
There would be images with labels that can explain the image.

Answer (score 12):

There are plenty of ways to do it

- If you application is iOS6+ only and don't need to support iOS5, you can use [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) to implement it. You will need to build some custom layout -- see [session 219 of WWDC'12 here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) after you have logged in using your Apple ID. You can also find plenty of tutorials on the net, simply google for the `UICollectionView` keyword.
- If you need to support iOS5 or earlier, or if you don't want to build your own custom `UICollectionViewLayout`, you can use some of the already made classes -- there are a lot of them around on the net. One of the most famous being **[iCaroussel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) on github**, which is free, compatible with multiple versions of iOS (not only iOS6), and allows you to do almost every kind of caroussel, including `iCarouselTypeCoverFlow` and `iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2` types (see the README on its github)

Answer (score 8):

A UICollectionView in iOS6 will allow you to do this.  Look at the WWDC 2012 Videos (on developer.apple.com):

- Session 205 - Introducing Collection Views
- Session 219 - Advanced Collection Views and Building Custom Layouts

To get the videos:

- Login to developer.apple.com and click on "iOS Dev Center" (on the left)
- Then under "Development Videos" (on the left) click on WWDC 2012
- You may be prompted to sign-in again but after that you can just click on the video
- All the WWDC 2012 videos are also available on iTunesU

The videos also show example code.

There is also example code on Github:
[Coverflow example](https://github.com/schwa/Coverflow)

Comment: @GiovanniFilaferro: Answer updated with more info.

Comment: "Look at a video" not a good solution because it takes too much time to seek a non-textual source for the precise solution. If possible, could you please give precise times during those videos that answer the question, or just copy the answer from the slide into stackoverflow?

Comment: @Cindeselia:Absolutely not.  The question was "how to create a coverflow" and the videos will walk you through the code you would need to write.  There is not one moment when all the code is on-screen and even if there was you should follow the video to understand the code you are including in your project.  Stackoverflow is also not a code-writing service. If you just want to include some code and not understand what you are using then use the Github code in the answer from AliSoftware.

Comment: @Robotic Cat: I understand this site is not a codewriting service, and I was and am not asking for code.  But "follow the video" is very lazy advice: I don't have the time or need to watch a 60-min (or in some cases longer) video, and the question doesn't take that long to be answered.

Comment: @Robotic Cat: Text can be read, seeked, and searched to the exact point where the point of confusion is, and is therefore preferable to sitting & sifting through half an hour of useless information. SO's benefit is solving problems specifically, and you can do that *without* writing code.  You do that by typing a textual answer succinctly, addressing the problem at hand, instead of flooding the thread with links.

Comment: Read this: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/video-tutorials-are-the-bane-of-my-existence/

Comment: @Cindeselia:`1.`This was not an appropriate question for StackOverflow as defined within the FAQ (hence it was closed) and as such the answer is perfectly fine. `2.`Bad luck you don't have time to write something yourself - I'm still not writing it for you. `3.`I like video tutorials (especially the WWDC videos) and I hope that more of them are produced.