# UIScrollView or UICollectionView - Paged with scaled adjacent pages

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm currently using a UIScrollView with pagingEnabled so that you can see a portion of adjacent pages. But I want the adjacent pages to scale down the farther away from center they get. They should scale to a minimum scale, say 50%.

This video shows exactly what I would like :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzQjYUYZmJM

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Show the code you have written so far to achieve this and what exactly is does wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue with `UIScrollView` take a look at [AHCarousel](https://github.com/sania-ashraf-confiz/AHCarousel).

But, it would be much easier and nicer done with `UICollectionView`. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769719/implementing-a-coverflow-view) should help you. [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) is very famous implementation of what you probably need.

Comment: iCarousel will do what I need thanks. The iCarouselTypeCylinder type is close enough to what I need